# How to move Exchange 2003 mailbox or store from 2003 to 2007 on separate networks?

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange-migration

I have an exchange sever 2003 installed and working. I have a new exchange 2007 server on another network. The two networks are completely separate with no connection. How can I take the 2003 mailboxes and put them on the new 2007 system? The move mailbox normal option on 2007 will not be able to see the old 2003 exchange server.

I was hoping I could just copy the database and mount it, but this doesnot seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Nope-- you can't just move the database around. It's too bad, but that's just the way the product is designed / implemented.

Your best bet is to [ExMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=429163ec-dcdf-47dc-96da-1c12d67327d5) out the data from the source server, and [import](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691363.aspx) it into the Exchange 2007 server.

More background on ExMerge: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174197

Bear in mind that replies to the imported messages may fail and modifications to old calendar items may not work right because the X500 addresses from the original Exchange install won't be assigned to the mailboxes in the new Exchange install. There are some details about that problem here: http://blogs.technet.com/sbs/archive/2009/05/21/cannot-reply-to-old-emails-or-modify-old-calendar-items-after-pst-mail-migration.aspx

Basically, you need the legacyExchangeDN from the old Exchange install to be added to the new recipients as an X500 format proxyAddress entry. It's not too bad to do, once you know what to do.

Answer (score 3):

Exmerge is a tool used to extract mailbox information from a MS Exchange server. If the user's mailbox is greater than 2 gigabytes of information, each component needs to be exported separately. This means the inbox e-mails need to be exported in groups no greater than two gigabytes in size. **The Exmerge tool allows you to export mailbox information based on search criteria such as date or subject**. This can be used to export messages from a mailbox that is over two gigabytes in size. Example:

1. **set Year=%Date:~8%**
2. **set Month=%Date:~3,2%**
3. **set Day=%Date:~0,2%**
4. **F:\ExMergeIni.exe SelectMessageEndDate "%Month%/%Day%/%Year% 23:59:58" -f "F:\Exmerge2GB.ini"**
5. Or reduce the mailbox size

Answer (score 0):

[Exmerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=429163ec-dcdf-47dc-96da-1c12d67327d5&displaylang=en) will allow you to backup users mailboxes to .pst files from your Exchange 2003 server, and then re-import them back onto the Exchange 2007 server.

Comment: I tried the Exmerge and found that I could export the data to a PST file. When I try to import the PST file on the Exchange 2007 it errors saying you can not import a pst file on a 64-bit server.

Comment: You have to go to a client running Outlook like an XP, Vista or 7 workstation. I had the same issue. Import the .pst from there.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that Exmerge cannot export mailboxes larger than 2GB because it uses the old format PST files and these are limited to 2GB. For mailboxes bigger than 2GB you'll need to export them with Outlook.

JR

Comment: I've used date ranges in ExMerge to get around the 2GB limit. It's clunky, but it works.